# clean future builder for new data

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

i'm using a builder for a search page in my application, basically i get data from a json file, 
my issue is that if i try to search for a new word, the old result will still be shown and the new one are going to be shown under them.

here is how i get data from my website:

```
  Future<List<Note>> fetchNotes() async {
  var url = 'https://sample.com/';

  var response = await http.get(url + _controller.text.trim());
  var notes = List<Note>();

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var notesJson = json.decode(response.body);
    for (var noteJson in notesJson) {
      notes.add(Note.fromJson(noteJson));
    }
  } else {
    ercode = 1;
  }
  return notes;
}

fetchNotes().then((value) {
  setState(() {
    _notes.addAll(value);
  });
});
if (_notes[0] == null) {
  ercode = 2;
 }
}
```

and i display data like this:

[here is full example for showing that data](https://pastebin.com/dan5SU1p)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use "clear()".

```
fetchNotes().then((value) {
  setState(() {
    _notes.clear();
    _notes.addAll(value);
  });
});
```